# Why is my random number generator returning negative values

Tags: java, random

I have made a very basic linear congruential generator (or at least I think I have) however it returns some crazy values including negative numbers. I cant for the life of me figure out why, any help very welcome. My code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    long a = 252149039;
    int c = 11;
    long m =(long) Math.pow(2, 48);
    long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("How many Random numbers would you like to get?");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= number;i++) {
        seed = ((a*seed)+c) % m;
        System.out.println(seed);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Never "roll your own" crypto or RNG. Use a trusted library, and follow its instructions carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds. 
 So, it may return big numbers such as  `1508797287829`.

Multiplying  a number such as `1508797287829` by `252149039` (=`380441786171888746331`) :

```
... 
long a = 252149039;
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
seed = ((a*seed)+c) % m;
```

produces an overflow for the `long seed` variable as `Long.MAX_VALUE` is defined as `2^63 - 1` (=`9223372036854775807`).

---

To represent an arbitrary-precision integer, you could use `BigInteger`.

Note that the class is immutable.

You could declare `seed` as a `BigInteger`.

```
BigInteger seed = BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

And use it in this way :

```
seed = seed.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(a))
           .add(BigInteger.valueOf(c))
           .mod(BigInteger.valueOf(m));
```

Comment: can you show me how to correct this? I guess I can use bigInteger but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: It is a way indeed. I updated with an example. Note that you have `mod()` and `remainder()` to compute the modulo. In your use case where you cannot have negative numbers, they should have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting overflow errors. A java <s>int</s> long can only hold values up to 2^63-1, anything bigger than that wraps around. The mechanics of how this work deal with two's compliment integer representation, and the shortest fix would be to add

```
seed = seed >= 0 ? seed : seed + m
```

just before you print seed.